# Can VSTO update/refresh an Office 2007 Ribbon XML menu control

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am already using the Ribbon with XML to add controls to the inspector of a received mail item in Office 2007.

I now want to add a menu/Combo box as well.  The problem is that it takes too long to generate the list of items.

Basically is it possible to let the Ribbon be generated and then add the items once they are ready?

I envisage something like:

1. Create the ribbon with an empty menu
2. Start a new thread and send it off to get data (thread safe stuff no office)
3. Get back on the office thread and add the list to the menu

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it is possible with the use of a DynamicMenu control.  Using a numbered list for my answer here is what I did.

1. Let office show the UI (in this case an Outlook Inspector)
2. Get the text of the Email Item and then start a new thread to process
3. When processing is finished get back onto the main UI Thread.
4. In the Ribbon XML an "empty" DynamicManu exists with a callback for its data
5. If the result is there is no data then call invalidate and the getVisible call back sets the control to false.  Control dissappears.
6. If there is data to add then invalidate and allow the control to now read the data in the callback.

I would like to thank my secretary for editing my post

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is difficult to achieve. In Standard ribbon control, values are rather static. They are loaded in to the controls before the ribbon is actually shown. I am not sure if there is a way to intercept it.